# Cannot read type blob using OleDbDataReader

Tags: vb.net, oracle, blob, oledbdatareader

I am trying to retrieve blob data from oracle database using OleDbConnection, but it is returning this error "Unspecified error, Oracle error occurred, but error message could not be retrieved from Oracle.Data type is not supported." I can retrieve fields with other types (varchar,number...) normally except blob. Any help is appreciated, below is my code:

```
Dim PictureCol As Integer = 0
Dim DestFilePath = "C:\testBlob.dat"
Dim Conn As New OleDbConnection

Conn.ConnectionString = GetConnectionString()
Conn.Open()
Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("SELECT d.document_file from library_documents d d.CATEGORY_ID=1 ", Conn)

Dim dr As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader

dr.Read()
Dim b(dr.GetBytes(PictureCol, 0, Nothing, 0, Integer.MaxValue) - 1) As Byte
dr.GetBytes(PictureCol, 0, b, 0, b.Length)
dr.Close()
Conn.Close()
Dim fs As New System.IO.FileStream(DestFilePath, IO.FileMode.Create, IO.FileAccess.Write)
fs.Write(b, 0, b.Length)
fs.Close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by using oraclecommand instead of OleDB